# View not displaying from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a basic controller:

```
using System.Web Mvc;

namespace MainProject.Controllers
{
   public class Main : Controllers
   {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
           return View();
      }
   }
}
```

with a view:

View/
    Main/
        Index.cshtml

And yet it doesn't return the page, it just the resource cannot be found. What am I missing here?

localhost:60555/Main/Index

Comment: What URL are you going to?

Comment: Provide your route configuration

Comment: you should have the view linked to your controller in the routeConfig.

Comment: OK maybe thats what I'm missing, where do i go to do that

Comment: @athar that makes no sense. You don't have to link views to controllers in your routing configuration.

Comment: This is not a controller. `public class Main : Controllers`. Did you mean `public class MainController : Controller`?

Comment: @CodeCaster i'm amazed you caught that.  kudos to you

Comment: ok ill try that then

Comment: `MainController` should inherit from `Controller` not `Controllers`

Comment: Isn't it `Views` instead of `View`?

Comment: Stop trying everything and start by reading [ask]. There's a _lot_ wrong with this code and the claims in your question. Be very specific and very accurate, don't cobble together an example that somewhat resembles your actual situation. Create a new project if you must, **before** asking a new question, to create a [mcve] to reproduce the actual problem you're having.

Comment: @CodeCaster I stand corrected. The URL and controller are mapped in the routeConfig. The views are picked based on the naming of the controllers and actions.

Answer (score 1):

try the below changed code it will surely work for you

your code:

```
using System.Web Mvc;
    namespace MainProject.Controllers
    {
       public class Main : Controllers
       {
          public ActionResult Index()
          {
               return View();
          }
       }
    }
```

Changed code :

```
  using System.Web Mvc;
    namespace MainProject.Controllers
    {
        public class MainController : Controller
        {

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

    }
```

Hope it was helpful

Thanks

Karthik